# AVAudioPlayer is nil for undefined reasons [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, null

i am new in Swift development and I am trying to write some music app, but when i try to run my app i see smth like this:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)
```

Here is my code: 
I declared `var avPlayer:AVAudioPlayer!` like a global variable

```
// button to play random track
@IBAction func playRandomTrack(sender: AnyObject) {
    var str = "https://api.vk.com/method/audio.get?user_id="+uid+"&v=5.28&access_token="+uat

    Alamofire.request(.GET, str)
        .responseJSON {(request, response, JSON, error) in
            let results: NSDictionary = JSON?.valueForKey("response") as NSDictionary
            let digit = results.valueForKey("items")!.count()

            let randomSong = UInt(self.randNum(digit))

            let songs:NSArray = results.valueForKey("items") as NSArray

            let songName: NSString = songs.objectAtIndex(Int(randomSong)).valueForKey("title") as NSString
            let songArtist: NSString = songs.objectAtIndex(Int(randomSong)).valueForKey("artist") as NSString
            let songUrl: NSString = songs.objectAtIndex(Int(randomSong)).valueForKey("url") as NSString
            let infoArray: NSArray = [songName, songArtist, songUrl] as NSArray


            self.songName.text = songName
            self.groupName.text = songArtist

            let cleanurl = songUrl.componentsSeparatedByString("?")
            let finalUrl: NSString = cleanurl[0] as NSString
            let fileURL = NSURL(string: finalUrl)!

            println(fileURL) ---- link of my audio file

            self.avPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileURL, error: nil)
            println(self.avPlayer) ---- nil
            self.avPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            self.avPlayer.play()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved via using AVPlayer instead AVAudioPlayer.